# Why does the printf function affect my speller program?

Tags: c, cs50

I am using a hash function from the internet and when I use a print function before the return statement, it makes my program correct, but if I remove it, it becomes bugged again... like literally frustrating because I can do `printf("asfasfnasfnk\n");` and it would output correctly but the moment I delete the printf function its bugged again...

```
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    /* credits to...
     *https://www.reddit.com/r/cs50/comments/1x6vc8/pset6_trie_vs_hashtable/
     */
    unsigned long hash = 0;
    int n  = strlen(word);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        hash = (hash << 2) ^ word[i];
    }
    return hash % N;
}
```

Output:

```
MISSPELLED WORDS

A
is
not
a
caterpillar

WORDS MISSPELLED:     5
WORDS IN DICTIONARY:  2
WORDS IN TEXT:        6
TIME IN load:         0.00
TIME IN check:        0.00
TIME IN size:         0.00
TIME IN unload:       0.00
TIME IN TOTAL:        0.00
```

```
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    /* credits to...
     *https://www.reddit.com/r/cs50/comments/1x6vc8/pset6_trie_vs_hashtable/
     */
    unsigned long hash = 0;
    int n  = strlen(word);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        hash = (hash << 2) ^ word[i];
    }
    printf("%s -> %lu\n", word, hash%N);
    return hash % N;
}
```

Output:

```
cat -> 1984
caterpillar -> 109622

MISSPELLED WORDS

a -> 97
A
cat -> 1984
is -> 471
is
not -> 1832
not
a -> 97
a
caterpillar -> 109622

WORDS MISSPELLED:     4
WORDS IN DICTIONARY:  2
WORDS IN TEXT:        6
TIME IN load:         0.00
TIME IN check:        0.00
TIME IN size:         0.00
TIME IN unload:       0.00
TIME IN TOTAL:        0.00
```

The words in the dictionary is cat and caterpillar, the words in the text is "A cat is not a caterpillar"

Functions:

```
// Implements a dictionary's functionality
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

// Number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = 200000;

// Hash table
node *table[N];

// Returns true if word is in dictionary else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    // TODO
    int len = strlen(word);
    char *copy = malloc(sizeof(char) * len + 1);
    // change into lowercase the word
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
            copy[i] = tolower(word[i]);
    }
    // get the index by using the hash function
    int index = hash(copy);

    node *tmp = table[index];
    // check if the word is in the hash table
    while (tmp != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(tmp->word, copy) == 0)
        {
            free(copy);
            return true;
        }

        tmp = tmp->next;
    }

    free(copy);
    return false;
}

// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    /* credits to...
     *https://www.reddit.com/r/cs50/comments/1x6vc8/pset6_trie_vs_hashtable/
     */
    unsigned long hash = 0;
    int n  = strlen(word);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        hash = (hash << 2) ^ word[i];
    }
    return hash % N;
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    // TODO
    char *words = malloc(sizeof(char) * (LENGTH + 1));
    if (words == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    // initialize the hash table to NULL
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        table[i] = NULL;
    }

    // open dictionary file
    FILE *indata = fopen(dictionary, "r");


    // 1 character for '\0' and another for '\n' because fgets takes a trailing new line
    // when it reads 'man' the value of words will be "man\n\0" so meaning 2 extra characters
    while (fgets(words, LENGTH + 2, indata) != NULL)
    {
        // get rid of the trailing new line from fgets
        words[strlen(words) - 1] = '\0';

        // allocate memory for the newNode
        node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (newNode == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // get the index by using the hash function
        int index = hash(words);

        strcpy(newNode->word, words);
        // make the newNode the head of the list
        newNode->next = table[index];
        table[index] = newNode;

    }

    // free memory and close the opened file
    free(words);
    fclose(indata);
    return true;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    // TODO
    // counter of words loaded
    unsigned int counter = 0;
    // loop through the hash table
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        node *tmp = table[i];

        while (tmp != NULL)
        {
            counter++;
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful else false
bool unload(void)
{
    // TODO
    // loop through the whole hash table
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        while (table[i] != NULL)
        {
            node *tmp = table[i]->next;
            free(table[i]);
            table[i] = tmp;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What's N (as opposed to n)?

Comment: "it becomes bugged again" How exactly? Is `word` a NULL-terminated char array? Please, post a [mre].

Comment: You need to give us enough code to replicate the error. If you can't replicate the error without code to call this function, then the bug is just as likely to be in the calling code as this code. (Update: And, of course, it was.)

Comment: This does not compile. And it is not a [mcve] (focus on minimal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// TODO
int len = strlen(word);
char *copy = malloc(sizeof(char) * len + 1);
// change into lowercase the word
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
        copy[i] = tolower(word[i]);
}
// get the index by using the hash function
int index = hash(copy);
```

Notice that `+ 1` in the `malloc`. Why is that there? It's to allow space for the terminating zero byte that marks the end of the string.

Say the string is "test". Then `strlen` will return 4. Your loop will iterate from 0 to 3 inclusive, copying the four letters in the word.

But you will not copy the terminating zero byte on the end of the string. When `hash` calls `strlen` on `copy`, who knows what value it will get since what you have passed it is not a legal string.

Change the condition in the `for` loop to `i <= len`.

Comment: Well shit, thank you so much been debugging for almost 3 hrs now and that was such a simple bug..